# Pick text from a fixed cell to be included

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code where I'm trying to pick all files from a particular folder. Now, what I want to do is the user can just enter the folder name in a cell and VBA directly picks the folder name from there. So, the user does not have to open the source code.

**This is my VBA code:**

```
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "C:\Users\20011608\Desktop\Sephora\Automated Reports\Presented - Door\Door-Brand (Sephora Extracted)\MAR\"

Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
   Do While Filename <> ""
   Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
      For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
      Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
   Next Sheet
      Workbooks(Filename).Close
      Filename = Dir()
   Loop
End Sub
```

I want my VBA code to pick my folder address under path directly from a cell C4 instead to opening the source code to paste the folder address under Path.

Folder address pasted in a excel sheet from where VBA can pick the folder address to be added under path

[image]

Comment: What's your question then? What have you tried? What similar questions here on SO have you researched?

Comment: How can I pick the text from a fixed cell and pasted it in the VBA code without opening the source code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=folder+picker+vba